# Remove the default white color of Button in flutter when Border radius and backgroudn image is used

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Just to practice API I am developing this application. The buttons are arranged in row and background image is attached but some beauty is decreased after we add backgound image.
The code for the application is:

```
CustomButton.dart: this is class for the button.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButton{
  var buttonName;
  CustomButton(this.buttonName);
  Widget homeButtons(){
    return  Material(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text(this.buttonName),
                    onPressed: (){},
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    splashColor: Colors.pink,
                    highlightColor: Colors.green,
                    textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
                    highlightElevation: 2,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
  }
}
```

And the code for the home page is:

```
Home.dart: This is class for HomePage.

import 'package:daily_laugh/buttons/CustomButton.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Laugh Daily",
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      bottomOpacity: 0.2,
      ),
      body: Container(
        
        decoration: BoxDecoration(

          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            (new CustomButton("Jokes")).homeButtons(),
            SizedBox(width: 15,),
            (new CustomButton("Memes")).homeButtons(),
            SizedBox(width: 15,),
            (new CustomButton("Face Similarity")).homeButtons(),
            SizedBox(width: 15,),
        
          ],
        ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

For Homepage:

```
import 'package:daily_laugh/screens/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: "Laugh Daily",
  home: Home(),
));
```

After the execution we get this output and the white part pointed by arrow needs to be removed:
[image: That white bakground created after Boarder Radius is used in button is to be removed.]

Comment: use ClipRRect instead of buuton

Answer (score 1):

In CustomButton you need to set the Material color as transparent

```
Widget homeButtons() {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: MaterialButton(
```

Comment: Thank you @Aby Bermen .. Sometimes small things make great change.